# Change border color of nested div when parent div has class added after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jquery drag and drop.  When the draggable element is dropped onto the correct slot, the draggable div gets a class added ('correct') to change background color.

Now, I want to change the border color of a nested div with the class 'info' in the draggable div when the parent div gets the class added.  How can I modify the code below to acheive this?

I have tried adding $('.info').addClass( 'correct' ); here:

```
ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
$('.info').addClass( 'correct' );
ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
```

Whilst this adds the class to .info as .info.correct OK, it also does this for all the other elements that have the info class...I just want it to change for that div when the parent gets the class added after dropping on the correct slot...not the other divs that have the info class...

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="elements">
    <div class="element" id="element_1" data-link="element_1.html">Element 1<a href="#" class="info">i</a></div>
     <div class="element" id="element_2" data-link="element_2.html">Element 2<a href="#" class="info">i</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slots">
    <div id="slot_1"></div>
      <div id="slot_2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#element_1').data( 'number', 1 ).attr( 'id', 'element'+1 ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#elements div',
      cursor: 'hand',
      revert: true
    } );

    $('#element_2').data( 'number', 2 ).attr( 'id', 'element'+2 ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#elements div',
      cursor: 'hand',
      revert: true
    } );

    $('#slot_1').data( 'number', 1 ).droppable( {
      accept: '#elements div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleElementDrop
    } );

       $('#slot_2').data( 'number', 2 ).droppable( {
      accept: '#elements div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleElementDrop
    } );
}

function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var elementNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == elementNumber ) {

ui.draggable.css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
ui.draggable.click(function(e) {  
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
    });
    $('.info').addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PP6HS/

Comment: Fiddle only shows one instance, so it's difficult to say among multiple. I'd say it's probably just a simply issue of traversal, something probably needs `ui.draggable.parent().find('.info').addClass('correct')` somewhere to target only the `.info` within the draggable's parent.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show two instances...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to traverse the original element by using the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector.

```
ui.draggable.parent().find('.info').addClass('correct')
```